# Add list of words to dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of words, and I want to add them to a dictionary and count how many times each word occurs.

Comment: What have you tried? What you want is a histogram. You can easily build one using `from collections import defaultdict; d = defaultdict(int); d[word] += 1`. There also is the `Counter` class in `collections`. You should look into these things.

Comment: What have you tried already? You need to show some effort before asking a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python comes with batteries included; using a [`collections.Counter()` object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

counts = Counter(list_of_words)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comments, they were really helpful. I know it's simple but I've been trying stupid stuff for ages and I finally did it.